# Cannot establish a connection to SQL Server over VPN using TCP protocol

Tags: sql, tcp, udp, vpn

During my daily work, I need to use the customer's Database. for this connection, first of all, I need to connect the VPN to customer's network, and then make the DB connection.

Normally, if this connection can be established using TCP protocol. But  sometimes I cannot connect to the DB. Then I track the network package, I found the connection is attempting connect to customer's DB using UDP protocol.

And now my network environment is using '172.16', if I change my network to '10.12', do the same connection, then change back to the '172.16' network, the connection can be established successfully.

Because the DB is in customer's side, I cannot check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first couple of things I'd look at:

- Firewall

  ... and ...
- Firewall

PS:
Yesterday I had a case where the customer's database could communicate by Windows host name or by "localhost" ... but NOT by IP, nor by hostname alias ... even though the client and the SQL Server were ON THE SAME PC!!!!

Windows firewall was OFF.  There wasn't any router between SQL server and the client (remember: same PC!).

But they installed a new A/V program ... that had it's own firewall ... and wouldn't allow any SQL Server connections.

PPS:
The correct approach, of course, is to configure firewall exceptions for all services you need (like MSSQL).

Comment: Firewall is disabled. I connect to the DB using the same client. Some times are OK, and some time cannot cannot make connection

Comment: So install a copy of Wireshark and trace the connection:  http://www.wireshark.org

Comment: Already installed Wireshark. I traced the package found if this connection can be established, the protocol is TCP, or failed, the protocol is UDP. So I don't know why

Comment: SQL Server communicates TDS data on TCP port 1433.  UDP port 1434 is used only for "setup information" to establish communication (e.g. the instance name, the TCP port#, etc).  These links might help:  http://vsql.blogspot.com/2004/06/what-udp-port-does-sql-server-listen.html  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Answer (score 0):

You could check with the customer's server administrator if the VPN access you have would have sufficient port/route access with customer's server database.

Normally VPN access allow outsider to gain access to internal network but it might be assigned by different router at the time you encountered problem. It isn't db problem, it is network issue.

Comment: The problem is that some time the connection is OK, some times is wrong. I am so puzzled